# Function-based generic views have been deprecated

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-1.3, django-1.4

> DeprecationWarning: Function-based generic views have been deprecated; use class-based views instead.

I keep getting this warning, when I'm running my site.  What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

Django 1.3 introduced [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/) and also added a range of generic class-based views. Django also has documentation about migrating [function-based views to class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views-migration/).

There is not really much more to say about it: your project currently uses function-based views whereas class-based views are the new way of creating views.